# How to backup a file when a file got edited using nodejs fs module?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am a beginner to nodejs please help me find this solution?

I need code that looks at a file and makes a backup of the file whenever it is changed and saved to the disk.

1. have to create backup in separate folder.
2. filenofoundexception if no particular file is not exists
3. changes are watched and saved immediately and console it

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    fs.watchFile("sample.txt", {
        persistent: true,
        interval: 2000,
    }, (curr, prev)=>{
        fs.writeFile('backupFile.text', prev)
    })
```

I tried got this error

```
node:internal/validators:223
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
```

Comment: Check the full stack trace; are you sure it's coming from here? (Also noting the docs indicate `fs.watch` is preferred.)

Comment: ya it worked, from where can i get previous file content, to store to another file